# stuck with one query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a table named `calci`. The following was the sample data

```
CREATE TABLE calci
    (RN int, FREQ int, price int)
;

INSERT INTO calci
    (RN, FREQ, price)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 3),
    (2, 2, 4),
    (3, 3, 5),
    (4, 4, 6),
    (5, 5, 7),
    (6, 6, 8),
    (7, 1, 5),
    (8, 2, 6),
    (9, 3, 9),
    (10, 4, 7),
    (11, 5, 5),
    (12, 6, 1),
    (13, 1, 3)
;
```

I required only 3 records based on the sum of `freq` (1-6)

The result should be like

```
price
33 -----sum of first 6 records    
33 -----sum of next six records    
3  -----sum of last six record i.e last record
```

Comment: Your sample data doesn't even have 18 records in it.  How do you want to handle this case?  What are the "last" 6 records here?

Comment: yes, even if it doesn't had sufficient amount of records it should their sum, for eg  at las we had only 4 records then last 4's records sum should be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check the following query which will solve the above problem

```
select sum(price) from calci  group by (rn- freq)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(price)
FROM calci
GROUP BY (RN - 1) / 6
HAVING (RN - 1) / 6 IN (0, 1)
UNION
SELECT SUM(price)
FROM calci
WHERE (RN - 1) / 6 = (SELECT (COUNT(*) - 1) / 6 FROM calci)
```

Comment: You are depending on the fact that there will be no gaps.

Comment: Let's make this assumption until the OP says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
;WITH t as (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(FREQ) OVER (ORDER BY RN, FREQ) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END change
    FROM calci
), tt as (
    SELECT *, SUM(change) OVER (ORDER BY RN) grouped
    FROM t)

SELECT SUM(price) sumFreq
FROM tt
GROUP BY grouped;
```

You can change `change` to `CASE WHEN FREQ - LAG(FREQ) OVER (ORDER BY RN, FREQ) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` for more flexibility to handle any jump in `FREQ` ;).

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
;WITH CTE (RN, FREQ, PRICE) AS
    (
    SELECT 1, 1,  3   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 2,  4   UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 3,  5   UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 4,  6   UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 5,  7   UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 6,  8   UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 1,  5   UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 2,  6   UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 3,  9   UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 4, 7   UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 5, 5   UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 6, 1   UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 1, 3
    ), CTE2(PRICE, RANK) AS
    (
    SELECT (PRICE) , DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY FREQ  ORDER BY RN ) FROM CTE 
    )
    SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM CTE2 GROUP BY RANK
```